# Rendering visualization of spectrogram efficiently

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to find a clever way to render a large spectrogram (say, fullscreen). A spectrogram is a coordinate-system, where the x-axis is time, the y-axis is frequency and the colour intensity is the magnitude of the frequency component, and it looks [like this (youtube).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZOFCgwkbSE)

What's interesting to note is that each frame, a new column (1 pixel wide) is new, *but the whole rest of the spectrum is the same*, only shifted left one pixel. Currently I'm just writing to a circular software buffer acting like an image, and drawing that - but it is obviously slow at high framerates and screensizes.

Is there any obvious solution to this problem, using OpenGL (or some software trick - has to be cross-platform, though)? Perhaps through some use of buffer on the GPU memory, with a shader that fills it (admittedly, i have a very vague understanding of OpenGL beyond drawing simple stuff)? It revolves around keeping the old data on the GPU memory as i see it.

Comment: How big is the source dataset to compute the FFT of? Ever since OpenGL Supported VBOs, you could use OpenCL to transform the data and spit it out as a OpenGL texture. Pushing the data to the GPU can be expensive though.

Comment: Well worst case is 60 fps * 65536 samples. I would like to keep the DSP part on the cpu though, since i also do some interpolation and analysis on the data - the fft is also not the only algorithm i use.

Answer (score 4):

Use a single channel texture for the waterfall (this is what you're drawing, a waterfall plot) in which you update one column or row at a time using `glTexSubImage`. By using `GL_WRAP` mode you can simply advance the texture coordinates beyond the bounds of the texture and it will, well, wrap. By moving the texture opposing to the update you can get the waterfall effect (i.e. moving spectrogram, with the updates coming in at the right edge).

To give the whole thing color, use the texture's values as an index into a transfer function LUT texture using a fragment shader.

Comment: Just to be certain: This is my idea of a waterfall plot: http://cdn.head-fi.org/5/50/5072c8ae_colby.txt.jpeg whereas what i want to draw is exactly like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Spectrogram-19thC.png

Which one are you describing?

Comment: Either way really.  You could generate the 3D plot by sampling the texture in your vertex shader and using that to offset the Z coordinate of your input vertices.

Comment: @Shaggi: I mean what you want to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GPU library for spectrogram calculations: nnAudio

https://github.com/KinWaiCheuk/nnAudio